# Django - get model in navbar

Tags: python, django, templates, navbar

I have a class in models.py :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    device = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Is there a way to access this model in navbar without creating entry in "views.py"? I would like to access similarly to {{ request.user.id }}.

Comment: Where is this navbar? How are you rendering it? Please show a complete example so we don't have to guess what you are talking about. See [mcve] for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Customer is related to User using [One-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relationship, you can get it through User object

```
request.user.customer
```

---

EDIT (after determining Customer and User are not really related):

You can write your own [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) which will return Customer object

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried this before in my 'navbar.html' like so:
{{ request.user.customer.id }} and it does not return anything even tho i have Customer with id 1.

Comment: is your user related to that particular customer

Comment: Well no. Because i made 'Customer' to serve guests clients - which only have 'device' assigned to the Customer object.

Comment: Why is your customer then related to User, makes no sense at all

Comment: So that when user is logged in he is assigned to Customer:
        try:
            customer = request.user.customer
        except:
            device = request.COOKIES['device']
            customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(device=device)

Comment: Look into my edit, still seems you are doing something pretty messy with a flow

Comment: What do you mean Look into my edit? 
Well now when i assigned the user to the customer I can access id by request.user.customer.id . 
So should I assign user to every Customer that adds something to cart or is there a better way? Maybe a temporary user?